# Edit and publish button/Icon is missing in Sharepoint 2019 On-premise site home page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I am Site Owner and having Full Control for all the sites, but the Edit button/Icon is Missing if i set the Page as Home Page.

[image: Edit Button Missing only on the home page of the site]

- if i go to any other site pages which is not a home page then i am able to see the edit button
- if i make any other page as home page then that page does not have Edit button

Comment: Is this issue occurs only on sub sites or all the sites, ?

Comment: This issue is only on all the site HomePage, say for Example if the Page is not a homepage then i can see the Edit and Publish button/icon.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problems, I suggest you install the latest SharePoint Server 2019 update package.

- [The security update for SharePoint Server 2019: October 12, 2021
  (KB5002028)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-october-12-2021-kb5002028-4a67eadf-3760-43c5-a167-86bb18053df9)
- [The update for SharePoint Server 2019 Language Pack: October 12,
  2021 (KB5002034)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-12-2021-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-language-pack-kb5002034-fddbb681-30c3-4679-9f49-5df31edf742f)